# Show top 3 'bad' systems on stacked bar of good & bad from dataframe (sort on one value but show both on graph)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe containing a change requests (CR), system, owner, and assessment (example)

```
CR  |system |  owner  |  assessment
A1  |Alpha  |  Alice  |  good
A2  |Alpha  |  Alice  |  good
A3  |Alpha  |  Alice  |  bad
B2  |Bravo  |  Bob    |  bad
B3  |Bravo  |  Bob    |  good
B4  |Bravo  |  Bob    |  bad
```

I'm trying to create a matplotlib graph of the top 3 systems with the worst assessment, but show a stacked bar graph in pyplot with both good and bad values.

This code (The CR has been dropped) gives me the right graphic, but the count is wrong as it counts good and bad separately.

```
table = df.groupby(['system','owner']).assessment.value_counts().nlargest(3)
chart = table.plot.barh(stacked=True, color= ['red','green'], fontsize=12)
```

The table looks like (actual extract):

```
system                     owner             assessment         
ALPHA                      Alice             good                   75
                                             bad                    60
BRAVO                      Bob               bad                    57
```

I've tried a number of statements to pull the top 3 worst systems and show a graph that shows both good and bad values on a horizontal stacked bar, but I can't seem to do both at the same time.

How do I sort on 'bad' number (60 and 57) but show good (75) and bad (60) on the same stacked bar? And how do I show the top 3 worst systems (most bad values)?

So the stacked bar result I' looking for looks like this:

```
Alpha    BBBBBBBBBGGGGGGGGG
Bravo    BBBBBBBBBBBBBB
Charlie  BBBGGGGGGGG
```

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my issue:

print(df.groupby(['system','owner']).Evaluation.value_counts().unstack(level=-1).nlargest(3,columns='bad').stack())